# Publishing website project, database date format will be the same or converted to the default host date format?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm developing a web application  and I'm using a gridview and sqldatasource.

```
I have some columns with type : Date.
```

In my control panel I set the format of the date for my country wich is : `dd.mm.yyyy`

- In this case , the Table Data of the database in c# will have the
  format for date : `dd.mm.yyyy`

I'm planing to publish my website on a host when I'll finish the project.

- But my question is :

If in my database the columns with Date are in format dd.mm.yyyy  , if I publish the database and use it with the website on the host , the dates will be dd.mm.yyyy or converted to the default format of the host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dates stored in the database do not have a certain format.  You chose, in your control panel, to show them with the format `dd.mm.yyyy`, but that doesn't change what's really stored in the DB.  They are similar to `DateTime` objects, representing a Date, not a string representing a date through a certain format.  How the dates are turned into strings depends on what culture settings are used when converting it to a string, which in most cases (e.g. [`DateTime.ToShortDateString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring.aspx)) should be the current culture.  If your code specifically said to use the format `dd.mm.yyyy`, then that will need to change.

So yes, it should be shown in the default format of the host.

(Side note: in .NET date-to-string formatting, `MM` is month, and `mm` is minutes.  You shouldn't need to deal with this in this case, but take care that you use the correct one any time you do.)